# Changing radio status of Wi-Fi software in windows 10 via command prompt or powershall

Tags: window, wifi, command-prompt, microsoft-teams, netsh

When we search on internet about how to turn on wifi using command prompt all solutions are about how to disable WLAN adapter which can be simply achieved by netsh command but what I was looking for is how to turn on or off my wifi without disabling network adapter.
After some digging what I found is this
In both cases wifi adaptor is enabled
When we run Netsh WLAN show interface while wifi is on we get this

````
There is 1 interface on the system:

    Name                   : Wi-Fi
    Description            : Qualcomm Atheros AR956x Wireless Network Adapter
    GUID                   : e1e71fab-3a91-4b36-a65b-2c68239b729f
    Physical address       : 24:fd:52:af:76:92
    State                  : disconnected
    Radio status           : Hardware On
                             Software On

    Hosted network status  : Not started```. 

But when wifi is off same command gives this. 

```netsh wlan>show interface

There is 1 interface on the system:

    Name                   : Wi-Fi
    Description            : Qualcomm Atheros AR956x Wireless Network Adapter
    GUID                   : e1e71fab-3a91-4b36-a65b-2c68239b729f
    Physical address       : 24:fd:52:af:76:92
    State                  : disconnected
    Radio status           : Hardware On
                             Software Off

    Hosted network status  :Not started```

So what I want is to change this radio status of software via command prompt or powershall
Please help me guys.
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the commands which worked in command prompt

Check radio status(no admin privileges required)

```
powershell Get-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty -Name "Wi-Fi" -AllProperties -RegistryKeyword "radioEnable"
```

To turn radio on (run as administrator)

```
powershell Set-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty -Name "Wi-Fi" -AllProperties -RegistryKeyword "radioEnable" -RegistryValue "1"
```

To turn radio off (run as administrator)

```
powershell Set-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty -Name "Wi-Fi" -AllProperties -RegistryKeyword "radioEnable" -RegistryValue "0"
```

to use these commands in powershell just remove powershell from beginning

Comment: This actually stopped working because of decoupling of WinRT from NetCore. "Built-in support for WinRT is removed from .NET 5.0": https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/18875 Proposed solution is to use C#/WinRT NuGet package https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/csharp-winrt/ to create working bindings - haven't tested that so can't confirm if it would work

Answer (score 3):

Check these posts they discuss exactly the things you want to achieve.

https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/9az53e/need_help_controlling_wifi/
https://superuser.com/questions/1168551/turn-on-off-bluetooth-radio-adapter-from-cmd-powershell-in-windows-10/1293303#1293303

**Excerpt from Reddit,
Credit goes to Reddit user All_Front_Random and Superuser Ben N**

To turn off the WiFi radio:

```
./Set-NetAdapterRadioPowerState.ps1 -WifiStatus Off`
```

To turn on the WiFi radio:

```
./Set-NetAdapterRadioPowerState.ps1 -WifiStatus On`
```

You could probably rework this a bit so that it checks the current status and simply toggles it on or off. Please let me know if you have any questions.

```
# Set-NetAdapterRadioPowerState.ps1
# credit to ben-n on superuser; adapted from https://superuser.com/a/1293303

[CmdletBinding()] Param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][ValidateSet('Off', 'On')][string]$WifiStatus
)

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime
$asTaskGeneric = ([System.WindowsRuntimeSystemExtensions].GetMethods() | ? { $_.Name -eq 'AsTask' -and $_.GetParameters().Count -eq 1 -and $_.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType.Name -eq 'IAsyncOperation`1' })[0]
Function Await($WinRtTask, $ResultType) {
    $asTask = $asTaskGeneric.MakeGenericMethod($ResultType)
    $netTask = $asTask.Invoke($null, @($WinRtTask))
    $netTask.Wait(-1) | Out-Null
    $netTask.Result
}
[Windows.Devices.Radios.Radio,Windows.System.Devices,ContentType=WindowsRuntime] | Out-Null
[Windows.Devices.Radios.RadioAccessStatus,Windows.System.Devices,ContentType=WindowsRuntime] | Out-Null
Await ([Windows.Devices.Radios.Radio]::RequestAccessAsync()) ([Windows.Devices.Radios.RadioAccessStatus]) | Out-Null
$radios = Await ([Windows.Devices.Radios.Radio]::GetRadiosAsync()) ([System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList[Windows.Devices.Radios.Radio]])
$wifi = $radios | ? { $_.Kind -eq 'WiFi' }
[Windows.Devices.Radios.RadioState,Windows.System.Devices,ContentType=WindowsRuntime] | Out-Null
Await ($wifi.SetStateAsync($WifiStatus)) ([Windows.Devices.Radios.RadioAccessStatus]) | Out-Null
```

Edit: Included code

Comment: Works with Windows 11, thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Interesting, for me it does not work in Windows 11. Windows still shows wifi as enabled.